# TyperError: Query dictionary values must be strings or sequences of strings

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I was previously using only pyodbc and pandas to reach out to a SQL Server to run a run a query and save that information into a csv file. Using this method **does work** but results in warnings that I feel was slowing down the program.

I'm trying to implement SQLAchemy but getting the TypeError above.

I read from the docs: [SQLAlchemy 1.4 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#pass-through-exact-pyodbc-string)

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Setting display options for the dataframe
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', None)

# Turning each row from the main .csv file into a dataframe.
df = pd.read_csv(r'''C:\Users\username\Downloads\py_tma_tables.csv''')

# Turning the dataframe into a list.
tma_table = df['table_name'].tolist()

# Connection setup.
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=DB_NAME;Trusted_Connection=yes')
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": cnxn})
engine = create_engine(connection_url)

df_list = []
count = 0
while count < 1:
    df1 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM " + tma_table[count], engine)
    df_list.append(df1)
    count += 1

df_count = 0
while df_count < len(df_list):
    for item in df_list:
        df_list[df_count].to_csv(tma_table[df_count] + ".csv", index=False, header=None, encoding='utf-8')
    df_count += 1
```

Running this returns:

```
TyperError: Query dictionary values must be strings or sequences of strings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
servername = 'server'
dbname = 'database'
sqlcon = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@' + servername + '/' + dbname + '?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')
```

Was then able to plug `sqlcon` in:

```
df_list = []
count = 0
while count < 1:
    df1 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM " + tma_table[count], sqlcon)
    df_list.append(df1)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=DB_NAME;Trusted_Connection=yes')
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": cnxn})
```

You are trying to pass a pyodbc Connection object in the `query=` dict. You need to pass the connection *string*:

```py
connection_string = "DSN=DB_NAME;Trusted_Connection=yes"
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
```